# Rust: How to read a config file at runtime and store in a global struct, accessible across threads?

Tags: configuration, rust, runtime, lifetime, ownership

This is my first project in Rust, and I think I'm missing something simple.

I'm attempting to create a simple Web API daemon that will receive POSTs of JSON, parse the JSON, and send an email using credentials provided in a config file.
90% of that problem has been easy.  I am struggling with "parse the config file at runtime".

I'm successfully use hyper and letter to receive JSON and send emails.  But I'd like this daemon to be configurable on the server, not at build-time (like most Linux / Unix daemons).  I've diligently followed through [here](https://omarabid.com/rust-intro).

I've created a config module, declared a struct, and used `lazy_static!{}` to store an initial version of the configuration struct.

I think I've boiled my problem down to one core question: How do I read and parse a config file, then *clone* the values into my struct?  Especially considering the fact that the size of those values can't be known at runtime...

e.g. `src/config.rs`

```rust
use std::sync::RwLock;
use serde::Deserialize;
use std::fs;
use std::io::prelude::*;

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Clone, Copy)]
pub struct RimfireCfg {
    pub verbose: u8,

    /* web api server config */
    pub listen_address: &'static str,

    /* mail server config */
    pub mailserver: &'static str,
    pub port:                u16,
    pub user:       &'static str,
    pub password:   &'static str,
}

lazy_static! {
    pub static ref CONFIG: RwLock<RimfireCfg> = RwLock::new(
        RimfireCfg {
            verbose: 0,
            listen_address: "127.0.0.1:3000",
            mailserver: "smtp-mail.outlook.com",
            port: 587,
            user: "",
            password: "",
        }
    );
}

impl RimfireCfg {
    pub fn init() -> Result<(), i32> {
        let mut w = CONFIG.write().unwrap();

        /* read the config file */
        let _lcfg: RimfireCfg =
            toml::from_slice(&fs::read("rimfire.toml").unwrap()).unwrap();

        // this is clearly wrong ...
        *w.listen_address = _lcfg.listen_address.clone();
        dbg!(*w);

        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn clone_config() -> RimfireCfg {
        let m = CONFIG.read().unwrap();

        *m
    }
}
```

and `src/main.rs`:

```rust
#[macro_use]
extern crate lazy_static;

mod config;

use config::RimfireCfg;

fn main() {
    let a = RimfireCfg::clone_config();

    dbg!(a);

    RimfireCfg::init().unwrap();

    let a = RimfireCfg::clone_config();

    dbg!(a);
}
```

Any thoughts?  suggestions?

Comment: If you're going to clone the config anyway, why not just construct it normally and share it between threads?

As for the config parsing itself, that depends on what format you use, you could either roll your own, or use something like [`toml`](https://crates.io/crates/toml) crate to do it for you. I see you already use serde, and `toml` depends on it :) Since you seem to write to it only once, there's no reason not to construct `Arc<Config>` in main and share it immutably without any locks by cloning just the `Arc`.

Comment: @Sahsahae could you form this into an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Your struct should store `String`s. `String`s are mutable and growable -- you can read data from a file into them, unlike `&'static str`s. `&'static str`s are usually only for constant string literals. I think using `String`s should get your example working with minimal tweaks.

Also, you can use `std::mem::swap()` to write the whole config at once. This is also more efficient because it doesn't require cloning strings.

I think the global static `RwLock` is reasonable if you want the config to be a global variable. Alternatively, as in Sahsahae's comment, you could avoid global state and pass an `Arc<RimfireCfg>` into anything that uses it. This is often cleaner.